Configuring API Platform with Multiple Modules and Authentication Methods
I'm encountering difficulties configuring API Platform to accommodate two modules with distinct prefixes and authentication methods. Specifically, I aim to set up one module (api/v2) with Bearer Authentication and another (b2c) with Basic Authentication.
Here's what I've attempted so far:
In 'config/routes/api_platform.yaml', I made the following changes:
b2c:
    resource: '../../src/B2C/'
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /b2c


Additionally, I updated '/config/packages/api_platform.yaml' with the following mappings:
mapping:
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/ApiV2'
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/B2C'

I would like to store ApiResources in two folders above and based on in which path would that resource be it will be either part of apiV2 or b2c. However, it appears that only the routing defined at the bottom (api_v2) is being applied, overriding the upper one (b2c).
Could someone provide insight into what might be causing this issue and suggest a resolution? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
